# How to find consolidated codecount for UCM component?

Tags: clearcase, cleartool, clearcase-ucm

We are having 9 UCM Components. we are using some in-build tool to find code count. but we need to use baseline for each component and place it in base clearcase view with those labels in config spec. It's a complex process altogether.

I want to find consolidated code count for all the elements in the component. Is there any easy way is there in Clearcase UCM commands?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a rootless component in order to define a composite baseline.

You would have one dedicated stream in which:

- you would update with the relevant baselines for each component (rebase)
- you would keep the rootless component with, in its dependencies all the other components
- you would create a baseline each time you want to freeze the list of baselines represented by the other components of that stream.

Creating a baseline when there are many read-only component and one rootless component with create a composite baseline on said rootless component, which will include the baselines of the other root-based components.

You can then have *another* stream, dedicated for reading a specific (composite) baseline of that rootless component: a view on that stream will give you access to the content of all the root-based components referenced by the composite baseline.

Comment: I am Sorry. Tough to understand. Can you rephrase it ?

Comment: @Samselvaprabu: What part don't you understand? You need 2 streams. One for *producing* a composite baseline based on the various baselines you need for each component, and one for *consulting* the content of a given composite baseline, in order to display with one (composite) baseline *n baselines* for *n* components (and you can run your "in-build tool to find code count" in that view based on that consulting stream). The idea is to be able to "consolidate" the access to all *n* components through *one* (composite) baseline.